# Click a ul link open a popup window

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make it when you click on a link in my UL it will open a simple popup box with a few line of text in that popup box.

```
  <ul>
   <li><a href="#introduction">About</a></li>
   <li><a href="#one">Portfolio</a></li>
   <li><a href="#">Contact</a></li>                 
   <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
  </ul>
```

So here is my UL code. I would like it for when someone clicks on "Contact" instead of linking it to a website or another page it will open a popup box i can put some contact info in.

Thanks!

Comment: You’d do that with JavaScript, yes. Have you tried writing something?

Comment: Would an "onclick" with an alert be enough?

Answer (score 1):

- You need to bind the event `click` to that link.
- Prevent the default behavior of that link when is clicked.

```js
document.getElementById("contact").onclick = function(e) { // bind the event click.
  e.preventDefault(); //Prevent the default behavior 
  alert('Some information from: ' + this.innerText + '\n\n Details:\n\n Ele from Earth!');
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><a href="#introduction">About</a></li>
  <li><a href="#one">Portfolio</a></li>
  <li><a href="#" id="contact">Contact</a></li>
  <li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
</ul>
```

Comment: Hey look here https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/165765/discussion-between-theonewhomade-and-ele

Comment: Thanks! Please open the chat tab. @Ele

Answer (score 0):

```
<ul>
<li><a href="#introduction">About</a></li>
<li><a href="#one">Portfolio</a></li>
<li><a href="#" onClick="a()">Contact</a></li>
<li><a href="#">Resume</a></li>
</ul>

<script>
function a () {
var contact = prompt("Add the contact.");
}
</script>
```

This will add a pop-up box. The rest of work lies with you.
It is your choice whether you want to use the value of the variable contact for displaying it on the screen or submitting it through a form.